# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar una consulta where de un modelo con una relación has_many de otro modelo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo los modelos:

```
class Caja < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :metras

  def self.con_metras
    select{|caja| caja.metras.size > 0}
  end

end
```

y

```
class Metra < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :caja

end
```

Una caja puede tener cero metras o muchas metras, necesito un método que me traiga sólo las cajas que tengan metras.

Para eso creé el método `Caja.con_metras`

Pero no me parece óptimo, ¿alquien me puede decir cómo puedo mejorar el método `self.con_metras`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando a tu modelo `Caja`:

```
scope :con_metras, -> { left_joins(:metras).where.not(metras: {id: nil}).distinct }
```

Comment: Estimado Lagos, se colgó el servidor de puma de tantas peticiones. :(

Comment: Este si camina fino: scope :con_metras, -> `{ left_outer_joins(:metras).where.not(metras: {id: nil}).distinct }`

Comment: Ahh genial que te funcionó, igual también cambié a `left_joins` en la respuesta, que en el fondo es un alias de `left_outer_joins` pero más corto. Saludos